# How to add a Stop icon to NetBeans 8.2

Tags: netbeans-8

On mac in NetBeans 8.2 I have a panel with a run button.

[image]

It's a bit strange to me after Visual Studio that there is no `Stop` button there. Is there a simple way to add it?

It should do the same as <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>delete</kbd> or `Stop Build/Run`

It's a bit tricky to restart it every time to test my changes.

[image]

Comment: What do you expect the "Stop" button to do?

Comment: Right click on the toolbar, choose "Customize" to add new buttons to the toolbar

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no `Stop` in `Project` folder in `Customize`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to easily do what you want.

The only place the **Stop** icon/button appears in NetBeans is in the **Output** window, and that is not available for reuse elsewhere, so NetBean's **View > Toolbars > Customize** functionality won't be of any use.

However....it is trivial to specify a shortcut key for the action associated with the **Run > Stop Build/Run** menu entry:

- In NetBeans select **Tools > Options**
- Click the **Keymap** icon. All the actions will be listed, along with their shortcuts.
- Type **Stop** in the **Search** field to locate the **Stop Build/Run** action.
- For the listed action named **Stop Build/Run** click the ellipsis and select **Edit...** from the popup menu.
- The cursor will move to the **Shortcut** field. You can now select any available shortcut. For example, in the screen shot below I pressed the ALT key, and then selected **ALT+T** from the drop menu of available shortcuts.

Then, you can just submit **ALT-T** from the keyboard to terminate a running application, instead clicking the **Stop** button in the **Output** window, or selecting **Run > Stop Build / Run**.

I know that you were asking for a toolbar solution, but in the absence of one perhaps a keyboard shortcut is a viable alternative.

[image: Stop action drop menu]